# Tomcat experts, /proxy/http/1.2.3.4/index.html to proxy http://1.2.3.4/index.html - possible?

Tags: proxy, tomcat, http, java

How to setup tomcat proxy so that, e.g., /proxy/http/1.2.3.4/index.html causes Tomcat to proxy http://1.2.3.4/index.html?

Comment: Are you trying to make an open proxy where any IP address substituted for 1.2.3.4 works; or just one specific destination server?

Answer (score 0):

This looks possible via urlrewritefilter. (A filter which can be used in Tomcat or any servlet engine) The rule would look like this (untested) but should work according to the docs:

```
 <rule>
   <from>^/proxy/http/[^/]+/(.*)</from>
   <to type='proxy'>http://$1/$2</to>
 </rule>
```

http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/index.html